# Codeigniter, jQuery and Ajax - Display new information when database is updated

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have a table called incoming_calls, with the fields id (auto increment field), phone_number (10 digit phone number), phone_login_id (4 digit login number), and date_created (where this is a current timestamp). I'm using codeigniter framework, and my problem is I need to make a javascript popup with the information stored in this table, but I need this popup only to happen when new information is present in the table. I'll need it to happen in real time. I have experience with PHP, MySQL, and javascript, but I'm not sure as to how to implement this with any sort of framework like jQuery or ajax with codeigniter because I haven't used them much. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Checkout [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm)

Comment: This helps, but I'm not sure as to how to implement something like this with codeigniter. It's codeigniter, jQuery, and ajax that I do not have experience with. I know that the controller is supposed to direct the information to the model, where the model processes the information, and handles all queries and functions, and the views are what is displayed clientside. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: CodeIgniter is very flexible and it does not make big difference. For example, in the regarded tutorial, Anything meant by php make it in the controller even database connectivity (this will break mvc but it is not matter now) and anything related to jquery place it in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to implement this functionality.
you can make a JavaScript function where you can make ajax request to your controller function that check if anything on database has been updated. but for checking updation you have to store last primary key in session or key or in hidden field . you can use JavaScript  function as

```
setTimeout(function(){
 test();// function that make ajax reqesut for checking new records.
}, 3000);

function test()
{

// your ajax code

}
```

idea is that after 3 second a this function is called and here you can pass your last id. after response update the last id.

in controller function you can use last id to make query for new records
as

```
select * from your table where id > last id
```

i hope this will help you.

i implement my own messaging system by using this idea in codeigniter.